# Feeds not recognizing CSV Title Rows

Tags: 8, feeds

I am trying to use Feeds to import/update content types, but it appears that it's not recognizing my mapping as I keep getting the error `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null`.

I have a test CSV header like this

```
O*NET-SOC Code,Delete,Title - Arabic,Title - English,Priority of Tasks,Task ID,Task - English,Task - Arabic,Task Type,Incumbents Responding,Date,Domain Source
```

We are using the `Task ID` (column 6) as our Title, so in the mapping I did the following:

[image]

The target `Title` is suppose to be mapped to the CSV header `Task ID`, but I get the `title cannot be null` error with this row whose `Task ID` is `1014`:

```
11-3131.00,Delete,<arabic text>,Training and Development Managers,3,1014,"Plan, develop, and provide training and staff development programs, using knowledge of the effectiveness of methods such as classroom training, demonstrations, on-the-job training, meetings, conferences, and workshops.",<arabic text>.,Core,27,07/2017,Occupational Expert
```

However, this csv row, whose Task ID is `1009` uploads without that error. :

```
11-3131.00,Delete,<arabic text>,Training and Development Managers,2,1009,"Evaluate instructor performance and the effectiveness of training programs, providing recommendations for improvement.",<arabic text>,Core,27,07/2017,Occupational Expert
```

What could cause the row with Task ID `1014` fail but the row with Task ID `1009` work without error?

NOTE: The question editor told me Arabic text isn't allowed, so I changed the Arabic text with  in the CSV rows

Comment: Is the Arabic text the same for each row? Try doing each row with empty string instead of Arabic text and see if the same issue occurs. The best thing to do to debug this is to create the simplest row you can that still breaks.

Comment: The arabic text is not the same, it's the translated version of their English counter-parts. However, I went ahead and tried to remove the Arabic text and left them as blank and I received the same error.

Comment: Try taking the row that works, and change the ID from `1009` to `1014`. Then does it still work?

Comment: Doing that made that row fail,

Comment: Then it appears the problem is not with the row itself, but with the ID number, somehow. I suggest looking at the code for where the error message comes from, and putting in some debug messages (like `dpm()`) for sanity checks

Comment: So just some random numbers don't work for IDs? Seems incredibly strange

Comment: That's why you should do some debugging and see what is really happening behind the scenes. Based on what you said so far, there's nothing we can do to help you past suggesting debug steps.

Comment: any recommendations on how you'd debug this particular module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117395/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-blondeswan).

Comment: The quotes aren't say, smart quotes, are they? Did you try quoting every value? Numbers should be fine for entity titles.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with the module not applying the title for BOTH translations, it was only applying it for the English translation, not the Arabic translation, so the whole insert would fail because the translation's title wasn't filled out.